# How do I change the start menu from classic view to WinXP Start Menu?

Tags: view, windows-xp, startmenu

I am working on a computer that is running WinXP but is using the classic windows start menu.  I've googled, but all I can find is how to change the Windows XP and/or Win7 Start Menu **TO** Classic Start Menu, but not how to change it **BACK** to Windows XP (Windows 7 has a utility to download to this).  There's no option for it in the control panel either...just Windows Classic Style or Windows Standard views.  I tried "taskbar and Start Menu" and although I see the new blue chrome design in the dialog box, it does not change the classic look to that  Win XP look.  Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See your first screenshot. First radio button is for XP Menu.